Problems writing a large text file in python
I have developed this semi-scientific code that acts as a TCP server. It listen for incoming messages, processes those and stores it in the computer RAM. Once the client disconnects, the PC attempts to write all the gathered data to a text file. The complete provided code is really girthy, but you can only concentrate on 2 functions:
print_decimal_chunks_to_file_and_terminal
write_accumulated_data_to_file
So the PC gathers data, an processes it to its final form like this:
2024-12-18 14:11:03.031651 - 0 CPS - 485 702 925 1152 1319 1440 1511 1568 1602 1624 1631 1631 1599 1534 1441 1344 1245 1124 994 896 774 645 513 390 283 189 5 0 5 5 34 133 289

This is an example of one completely processed data packet. Depending on the environment and my application use case, I can either expect only a few of those lines I will be writing to a file, but it is also possible I will have to write up to half a million of such lines to a text file.
Problem is that when I get more and more lines to write, it takes exponentially longer to complete the text file. For example: couple of thousand lines takes around few seconds, but 50k+ lines may take up to 15 minutes. 129k lines took half a day... I guess it should not be like that. I do not have any hardware limitations and I am ready to optimize much of the usual OS working conditions, but I want to believe its possible to write 500k lines in under 5-10 minutes somehow...
I did my initial research, but I am already using the memory mapped files, I do not use many write. commands, I try to do it all at once. Not much of quick fixes are left for me... So I am asking for help and observations on where are the bottlenecks in my code. I do not have much experience with python, but this time I can not fundamentally change the program architecture - I can not write data in small chunks as soon as it is received, I still have to write all buffer at once. Thank you for any help.
import socket
import struct
import numpy as np
import time
from datetime import datetime
import os
import threading
from collections import deque
import sys
from threading import Lock
import mmap
 
TARGET_IP = None
TARGET_PORT = 8000
 
UDP_MESSAGE = "ESP32AGAIN"
UDP_BROADCAST_IP = "255.255.255.255"  
UDP_BROADCAST_PORT = 55555 
 
BUFFER_SIZE = 128
NUM_TO_PRINT = 32
BUFFER_LIMIT = 500 * 1024 * 1024
 
write_lock = Lock()
buffer_queue = deque()  
timestamps = deque()  
cps_values = []
active_connection = False
total_logs_received = 0
client_connection = None
last_packet = None
start_time = None
end_time = None
filename = None
 
def process_data_chunk(data):
    result_array = (
        (((data >> 14) & 1) << 0) |
        (((data >> 13) & 1) << 1) |
        (((data >> 15) & 1) << 2) |
        (((data >> 4) & 1) << 3) |
        (((data >> 9) & 1) << 4) |
        (((data >> 17) & 1) << 5) |
        (((data >> 1) & 1) << 6) |
        (((data >> 5) & 1) << 7) |
        (((data >> 10) & 1) << 8) |
        (((data >> 3) & 1) << 9) |
        (((data >> 12) & 1) << 10) |
        (((data >> 2) & 1) << 11)
    )
    return result_array
def process_data(data):
    result_array = np.array([process_data_chunk(struct.unpack('I', data[i:i+4])[0]) for i in range(0, len(data), 4)])
    max_index = np.argmax(result_array)
    higher_indices = np.arange(0, max_index + 1) 
    lower_indices = np.arange(max_index, len(result_array))
    higher_elements = result_array[higher_indices]
    lower_elements = result_array[lower_indices]
    rearranged_buffer = np.concatenate([higher_elements, lower_elements])
    max_index_rearranged = np.argmax(rearranged_buffer)
    rearranged_buffer = np.roll(rearranged_buffer, 10 - max_index_rearranged)
    return rearranged_buffer
 
def print_decimal_chunks_to_file_and_terminal(data, file_path, timestamps, cps_values):
    global total_logs_received
    global filename
    try:
        data = list(data)
        timestamps = list(map(float, timestamps))  
        cps_values = list(cps_values)
        lines_to_write = []
 
        for i in range(len(data)):
            packet_data = data[i]
            timestamp = timestamps[i]
            cps = cps_values[i]
            formatted_timestamp = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.', time.localtime(timestamp)) + f"{timestamp:.6f}"[11:]
            formatted_cps = f"{max(0, int(cps) - 1):d}" if cps is not None else "N/A"
            line = f"{formatted_timestamp} - {formatted_cps} CPS - "
            formatted_line = " ".join(f"{max(num - 2048, 0):4d}" for num in packet_data)
            line += formatted_line
            lines_to_write.append(line + "\n")
            total_logs_received += 1
        data_to_write = ''.join(lines_to_write)
 
        if os.path.getsize(filename) == 0:
            first_line = lines_to_write[0]
            with open(filename, "a+") as file:
                file.write(first_line)
            lines_to_write = lines_to_write[1:]
 
 
        remaining_data = ''.join(lines_to_write).encode()
        data_length = len(remaining_data)
             
        with open(filename, "r+b") as file:
            file.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)
            current_size = file.tell()
            file.write(b'\0' * data_length) 
                 
            mmapped_file = mmap.mmap(file.fileno(), current_size + data_length)
            mmapped_file.seek(current_size)  
            mmapped_file.write(remaining_data)
            mmapped_file.close()
 
    except Exception as write_error:
        print(f"Error writing to file: {write_error}")
         
def count_formatted_logs_in_last_second(timestamps, current_timestamp):
    count = 0
    for ts in timestamps:
        if current_timestamp - ts < 1 and current_timestamp >= ts:
            count += 1
    return count
 
def calculate_cps(timestamps):
    cps_values = []
    for i in range(len(timestamps)):
        cps = count_formatted_logs_in_last_second(timestamps, timestamps[i])
        cps_values.append(cps)
    return cps_values
 
def broadcast_message():
    udp_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM, socket.IPPROTO_UDP)
    udp_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST, 1)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    udp_socket.sendto(UDP_MESSAGE.encode(), (UDP_BROADCAST_IP, UDP_BROADCAST_PORT))
    time.sleep(0.5)
    udp_socket.sendto(UDP_MESSAGE.encode(), (UDP_BROADCAST_IP, UDP_BROADCAST_PORT))
    udp_socket.close()
 
def write_accumulated_data_to_file():
    global buffer_queue
    global timestamps
    global cps_values
    global filename
 
    with write_lock:
        if buffer_queue and timestamps:
            try:
                cps_values = calculate_cps(timestamps)
                with open(filename, "a+") as file:
                    print_decimal_chunks_to_file_and_terminal(buffer_queue, file, timestamps, cps_values)
                    file.flush()   
                buffer_queue.clear()
                timestamps.clear()
                cps_values = []
 
            except Exception as write_error:
                print(f"Error writing to file: {write_error}")
 
def format_time(seconds):
    hours = int(seconds // 3600)
    minutes = int((seconds % 3600) // 60)
    seconds = int(seconds % 60)
    return f"{hours}h {minutes}m {seconds}s"
 
def handle_client(connection, address):
    global active_connection
    global buffer_queue
    global timestamps
    global cps_values
    global last_packet
    global end_time
    global start_time
    global filename
 
    try:
        buffer = bytearray(BUFFER_SIZE)
        reference_time = time.time() 
        start_perf_counter = time.perf_counter_ns() 
 
        start_time = reference_time
 
        while active_connection:
            try:
                total_received = 0
                while total_received < BUFFER_SIZE:
                    additional_data = connection.recv_into(buffer)
                    if additional_data == 0:
                        print(f"Connection closed by the client ({address}) at {time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')}")
                        active_connection = False
                        break
 
                    total_received += additional_data
 
                if not active_connection:
                    break
 
                elapsed_ns = time.perf_counter_ns() - start_perf_counter
                timestamp = reference_time + elapsed_ns / 1e9  
 
                if total_received == BUFFER_SIZE:
                    data = process_data(buffer)
                    buffer_queue.append(data)
                    timestamps.append(timestamp)
 
                    if len(buffer_queue) > BUFFER_LIMIT // (BUFFER_SIZE // 4):
                        print("Buffer size limit reached. Closing connection and writing data to file.")
                        threading.Thread(target=write_accumulated_data_to_file).start()
                        active_connection = False
                        break
 
                    cps = count_formatted_logs_in_last_second(timestamps, timestamp)
                    cps_values.append(cps)
 
            except Exception as receive_error:
                break
 
        if active_connection:
            end_perf_counter = time.perf_counter_ns()
            elapsed_ns = end_perf_counter - start_perf_counter
            end_time = reference_time + elapsed_ns / 1e9  
 
            last_packet = buffer[:BUFFER_SIZE]  
            buffer_queue.pop()
            last_packet_ints = struct.unpack("II", last_packet[:8])
 
            total_measurement_seconds = max(0, end_time - start_time - 5)
            total_measurement_time = format_time(total_measurement_seconds)
            network_congestion_time = format_time(last_packet_ints[0])
            network_congestion_events = last_packet_ints[1]
             
            summary_line = (
                f"Total measurement time: {total_measurement_time}. "
                f"Network congestion time: {network_congestion_time}. "
                f"Network congestion events: {network_congestion_events}"
            )
            print(f"Impulse count: {len(buffer_queue)}")
            print("Disconnection detected. Closing socket and writing data to file. Please wait... ")
            writer_thread = threading.Thread(target=write_accumulated_data_to_file)
            writer_thread.start()
            writer_thread.join()  
            active_connection = False
 
    finally:
        connection.close()
        with open(filename, "a+") as file:
                file.write("\n" + summary_line + "\n")
        print("Finished writing")
        print("Connection closed.")
         
def get_local_ip():
    try:
        hostname = socket.gethostname()
        ip_address = socket.gethostbyname(hostname)
        return ip_address
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error getting local IP address: {e}")
 
def timer_callback():
    if not buffer_queue:
        print("No pulses detected in 10 seconds, check your hardware setup")
 
def receive_data():
    global active_connection
    global client_connection
    global TARGET_IP
    global TARGET_PORT
 
    broadcast_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    broadcast_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    broadcast_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST, 1)
    broadcast_socket.bind(('0.0.0.0', 8000))  
 
    try:
        print("__________________________________________________________________________________________________________________")
        print("Listening for broadcast messages...")
        while True:
            data, address = broadcast_socket.recvfrom(1024)
            message = data.decode("utf-8")
            if message.strip() == "Scintilator":
                TARGET_IP = address[0]
                TARGET_PORT = address[1]  
                print(f"Subnet broadcast message received from {address}. IP and Port obtained: {TARGET_IP}:{TARGET_PORT}")
 
                time.sleep(0.1)
 
                broadcast_message = "Scintilator"
                broadcast_socket.sendto(broadcast_message.encode("utf-8"), (TARGET_IP,8000))  
                print("Recognition message sent.")
 
                active_connection = True
                break
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error receiving broadcast message: {e}")
    finally:
        broadcast_socket.close()
 
    if TARGET_IP and TARGET_PORT and active_connection:
        server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
 
        try:
            print(f"Listening for client connections on {TARGET_IP}:{TARGET_PORT}...")
            server_socket.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_NODELAY, 1)
            server_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_RCVBUF, 1048576)
 
            server_socket.bind((get_local_ip(), 8000))
            server_socket.listen()
 
            while True:
                if not active_connection:
                    break
 
                client_connection, client_address = server_socket.accept()
                print(f"Connected by {client_address}")
 
                while True:
                    input_bit = input("Enter 0 if you want to specify the measurement time, 1 if you want to specify the number of impulses: ")
                    if input_bit == 1:
                        timer = threading.Timer(10, timer_callback)
                        timer.start()
                    if input_bit in ['0', '1']:
                        break
                    else:
                        print("Invalid choice. Please enter 0 or 1.")
 
                while True:
                    user_input = float(input("Enter the parameter (in seconds or quantity of pulses accordingly) : "))
                    if ((input_bit == 0) and (user_input == 0)) or ((input_bit == 1) and (user_input<1)):
                        print("Invalid parameters entered")
                    else:
                        break
 
                print("Measurement started at", datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
 
                integer_part = int(user_input)
                fractional_part = user_input - integer_part
                 
                if input_bit == '0':
                    final_float = 2 * integer_part + fractional_part
                else:
                    final_float = 2 * integer_part + 1 + fractional_part
 
                user_input_packed = struct.pack("!f", final_float)
                client_connection.sendall(user_input_packed)
 
                handle_client(client_connection, client_address)
 
        except Exception as bind_error:
            print(f"Error during socket bind: {bind_error}")
 
        finally:
            threading.Thread(target=write_accumulated_data_to_file).start()
            server_socket.close()
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
 
    timestamp_str = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S", time.localtime())
    filename = os.path.splitext("Rezultatai.txt")[0] + " " + timestamp_str + os.path.splitext("Rezultatai.txt")[1]
    receive_data()
    while True:
        input_bit = input("Enter 0 if you want repeat, enter any other character if you want to terminate the program: ")
        timestamp_str = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S", time.localtime())
        filename = os.path.splitext("Rezultatai.txt")[0] + " " + timestamp_str + os.path.splitext("Rezultatai.txt")[1]
        if input_bit == '0':
            broadcast_message()
            sys.stdin.flush()
            sys.stdout.flush()
            receive_data()
        else:
            print("Program terminated")
            sys.exit(0)


"So I am asking for help and observations on where are the bottlenecks in my code" - Well, we would expect that you tell us what takes time here, as you are the one who has the data and can do the timing. Please note that we would expect a [mre] (strong emphasis on minimal) - and that trying to build one probably would help you a lot in finding the bottleneck.

Have you tried the more straight forward approach and found it a problem? I ask because if I write a file with 500k lines of text similar to your example it takes about a second.

I can't help wondering why the server needs to keep the data in memory. Why not just append to the target file as soon as you have a complete "message"?

I can not write the data lines as soon as those are received, because its an application where time is very critical, there is a high possibility there will be an incoming TCP packet, when the server is busy writing something to a text file. And as I told before, writing a file takes quite some time :) Just take it as a given that I have to write everything at once. Regarding the JonSG: could you please share your method?

@ViliusŽalėnas Writing to a flat file is very fast. Also, as it's TCP (and not UDP) you're not going to lose any messages

I tried that developing this code... However, it slows down the Ethernet part of this code significantly. I tried memory mapping, reducing system call count, tried different file formats such as hdf5 and csv, but I still get no significant improvement...
